# Which Control / Library should I use to draw 23 Images on a Canvas with 25 Hz?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, graphics

I am writing an app (c#, wpf) for analyzing sports data. I got the positional data of all players and the ball with 25 hz. 
Now I need to visualize the data in my app.

The Data looks like this:

```
public class singlecoords{
  public decimal x,y,z;
  public string timekey;
}


public static Dictionary<string, List<singlecoords>> matchscoords = new Dictionary<string, List<coords>>();
```

(1) I have the pitch as SVG Document which is rendered on a Canvas Control right now.

How should I draw the players and the ball to a control (stick with a canvas control?) to achieve a smooth performance?

I would need to draw 23 Objects (Images) for 25 times per second.

(2) Would it be better not to redraw the images on each cycle, but to just move them within the control?

Comment: WPF does not have a constant framerate. Look at OpenTK and the windowsFormsHostControl.

Comment: it does not need to be exactly 25hz. but it must look smooth

Comment: @EikeS Assuming  you are correct, there is nothing wrong with variable frame rates.  One need only apply the appropriate translation deltas based on time elapsed since last frame interpolating the sampled data.  Variable framerates is common in DX; XNA and Unity3D.  There is no need for 3rd party frameworks either.

Comment: @user2556555 WPF is powered by DirectX so it is very smooth.

Comment: Thanks Micky. So which Control should i use to wrap my pitch, players and the ball? Is a canvas control appropriate? or should i draw directly to my view / window?

Comment: Yes, in a grid, stackpanel etc. You could draw a series of paths, each with a transform. You could draw a polyline and alter the transform as a function of time.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms747393(v=vs.100).aspx.  Alternatively you could [render to a bitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) and display later into anything that accepts bitmaps. Much like rendering to an offscreen buffer